# Windows server 2003 Scheduling task Occasionally not working

Tags: windows, scheduling, task

Issue : Windows server 2003 Scheduling task Occasionally not working

Os    :    Windows server 2003, Enterprise edition, Sp2

Issue :    Scheduling task

```
       Task: - for every 1 min the exe application will be triggered.

       Occasionally not working ----- so we have to manually run the application then it will work perfect.
```

Application Type    :    Console application

Scheduling is running but the exe is not triggered

Could you please give me a solution for this issue ?

Regards,

laxman

Answer (score 0):

1. Check execution time of console application. There are chances that execution of console application is taking more than 1 min.
2. option in settings tab - "Allow task to be run on demand" is checked

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
 I checked the execution time of the application. 
Yes sometimes it may take more than 1 min also to complete the process. 
Even if the processing time is more than 1 min, after completing the current one. it will start the new one as per scheduling.
But occasionally the scheduling is in the running state but the exe is not triggered.
I think the problem is not in the console application which I am running.
It’s something to deal with task scheduling and its services or any other settings.